# Rollback происходит автоматически при сохранении сущности в БД

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

При сохранении записи в Бд постоянно происходят rollback. Вижу, что сущность сохранилась(получаю ее id). Но в базе этой сущности не оказывается. Может я как-то не так использую аннотацию `@Transactional`?

Dao:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends BaseEntity> implements BaseDao<T>{

protected static HibernateUtils utils = HibernateUtils.getInstance();


public long save(T entity) {

    Session session = utils.getSession();
    long id = (long) session.save(entity);
    return id;
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = DaoException.class)
public class BillServiceImpl implements BillService {


@Autowired
private BillDaoImpl billDao;

@Override
public long save(Bill entity) {
    try {
        return billDao.save(entity);
    } catch (DaoException dao) {
        throw new ServiceException();
    }
}
}
```

Web:

```
@RestController
public class AppController {


@Autowired
private BillService billService;

@RequestMapping("/billsave")
public void billsave(ModelAndView modelAndView){


    Bill bill = new BillBuilder
            .BillEntityBuilder()
            .password("1234567890")
            .build();

    long id = billService.save(bill);
    System.out.println(id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие - Container-Managed Transactions (`CMT`). Оно описывает процесс управления работой с БД, при котором контейнер, в котором работает ваше приложение (например, сервер приложений или фреймворк `Spring`), осуществляет контроль действий с БД - выдача вашему приложению соединений с БД, управление транзакциями и прочее. Аннотация `@Transactional` "работает" только если у вас настроено и используется CMT.

Наличие этой строчки - `Session session = utils.getSession()` - говорит о том, что скорее всего, ваше приложение само осуществляет процесс создания соединения с БД. В таких случаях контейнер не контролирует действия, выполняемые с полученным соединением с БД (сессией), а аннотация `@Transactional` игнорируется. Вам следует либо явно подтверждать завершение транзакции вызовом соответствующего метода, либо разбираться с настройкой `CMT` в вашем проекте.